# Spring Integration, jms Inbound gateway for WMQ; Unable to consume messages

Tags: jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I have recently started exploring Spring Integration as that is one of the option we want to evaluate for our project.

The issue i am facing is below.

I have created a JMS inbound gateway to listen to WMQ queue and i am expecting the inboudnd gateway (using DML) should pick up the messages as and when they are available on queue(event - driven).

But some how the example isn't working. It fails to pick messages from the queue. However i can see (using a tool) that there are consumers created on the queue. 
Help here is really appreaciated.

Code snippet below.

```
<bean id="mqFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="${mq.hostName}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/>
        <property name="queueManager" value="${mq.queueManager}"/>
        <property name="channel" value="${mq.channel}"/>
        <property name="transportType" value="${mq.transportType}"/>
        <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="${mq.SSLCipherSuite}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="inCachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqFactory" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestQueue-mq" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="${mq.example.queue}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="demoBean" class="com.jpmchase.example.spring.DemoBean">
</bean>
   <jms:inbound-gateway id="wMQ_in_gateway" concurrent-consumers="2" max-concurrent-consumers="5" connection-factory="inCachingConnectionFactory" request-destination="requestQueue-mq"
    request-channel="demoChannel"  />
<integration:channel id="demoChannel">
     </integration:channel>
<integration:service-activator input-channel="demoChannel" ref="demoBean"/>
```

Below is the service-activator java code.

```
enter @MessageEndpoint
```

public class DemoBean {

```
@ServiceActivator
public String upperCase(String input) {
    System.out.println("inside the service activator " + input);
    return "JMS response: " + input.toUpperCase();
}
```

here

Comment: what happens? Is there any log ?

Comment: Have you tried `MQConnectionFactory` directly with wrapping to the `CachingConnectionFactory`? And share, please, logs when `DEBUG` is switched on for the `org.springframework.integration` and `org.springframework.jms`

Comment: I do see belwo in the log when debug on.
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue:///PHxx.xTx.TO.Pxxx.DEV.VENUS' - trying to recover. Cause: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.<init>(MQMessageConsumer.java:497)
 at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createQConsumer(MQSession.java:3082)
 at com.ibm.ms

Comment: did you include jta.jar?

Comment: @Artem, i did have MqConnectionFactory given as parameter to CacheconnectionFactory . However what i noticed is ..the number of consumer on the queue goes on increasing . But none consumes the message from the queuq.

Comment: @Umapathy , i do not have jta.jar as dependancy . I can try that but otherwise i do see a log entry which says compo a t wMq_inbound_gateway started. Which is the name of the inbound gateway . Why would it fail to pick up a message even though i see consumers being created on the queue

Comment: @Umapathy, thx man adding jta.jar dependancy solved the problem.

Comment: com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms indicates the MQ JMS Migration mode is being used; you've not got PROVIDER_VERSION=6 set as a property on the connection factory (that I can see) therefore I suspect the Channel has the SHARECONV property set to 0. Would advise uping this to something at least positive (10default). 

Won't necessarily fix any underlying connectivity issues but will mean better usage of the MQ and JMS.